# Counting Elements

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to count the occurrence of a certain element using recursion, but I keep getting an array out of bounds error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a ={70,70,86,53};
        int number = 70;
        int done = occur(number, a);
        System.out.println(done);
    }

    public static int occur(int number, int[] a, int count) {
        int length = a.length;
        int count = 0;
        if (a[0] != number) {
            count += 0;
        } else {
            if (a[0] == number) {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        if (length == 0) {
            return count;
        }
        int[] a2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, a.length - 1);
        return occur(number, a2, count);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the first time that I see linear search implemented in O(n²).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two logic errors.

1) You need 3 parameters in your recursive methods : number to search, actual count of the search and actual array where search.
You don't specify any parameter for the actual count. So the information is lost in the next recursive call.

2) You compare **the first element** of the array to check if its values matches to the number to search :

```
if (a[0] == number) {
  count += 1;
}
```

but you remove **the last element** of the array in the sent parameter of the next recursive call :

```
int[] a2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, a.length - 1);
return occur(number, a2);
```

It will produce inaccurate results.

---

As a side note :

- you have a not required processing.
  What is the point from doing :

  `if (a[0] != number) {
       count += 0;
  }`

It doesn't increment the counter. So, it is useless

- the array copy could be avoided by adding a parameter that transmits at each call the current index to handle.

---

Here is a sample code with the corrections :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = { 70, 70, 86, 53 };
    int number = 70;
    int done = occur(number, 0, a, 0);
    System.out.println(done);
}

public static int occur(int number, int count, int[] a, int index) {

    if (index == a.length) {
        return count;
    }

    else if (a[index] == number) {
        count += 1;
    }

    return occur(number, count, a, ++index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!:) All of these were good answers, but this some seemed to work the best!

Answer (score 0):

check the length at the top of the method. When the length is 0 then you cannot access a[0].

Also instead of creating array everytime you can pass an index in the method and start the next recursion from that index.

Answer (score 0):

replace `occur(number, a);`
with
`Arrays.stream(a).filter(n -> a == n).count();`

Answer (score 0):

Few of things.

1. Better to pass an index then copy the array every time way faster
2. check the length (or the current index is length) at the beginning and return 0.
3. remove the if containing `count += 0` it's useless
4. replace the recursion with `return count + occur(number, a2)` to add the count from this iteration

you can drastically simply it down to this

```
public static int occur(int n, int i, int[] a)
{
   if(i == a.size())
   {
      return 0;
   }
   return a[i] == n ? 1 + occur(n, i+1, a) : occur(n, i+1, a);
}
```

Comment: @WebNeoRaven what do you mean I'm passing i as the index and using that. the initial call (assuming you want to count the whole array) is `int count = occur(number, 0, a);`

Comment: Yeah. My bad. False Alarm!